# Upload a image in a porltet Liferay

Tags: image, liferay, file-io

I am doing a portlet to create banners. I preferences I made the form with: **input type="file"** and the form **nctype='multipart/form-data'**

In the processAction I get the image, but I don't know how save it in the server, because I only get save in temporal instance portlet, but if I restart the server I lose the image.

This is my code to save the image:

```
    private boolean uploadFile( ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws ValidatorException, IOException, ReadOnlyException {
    try {
        // Si la request es del tipo multipart ...
        if (PortletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            DiskFileItemFactory diskFileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            PortletFileUpload servletFileUpload = new PortletFileUpload(diskFileItemFactory);
            servletFileUpload.setSizeMax(81920); // bytes
            List fileItemsList = servletFileUpload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator it = fileItemsList.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()){
            FileItem fileItem = (FileItem)it.next();
            if (fileItem.isFormField()){
            }
            else{
                String nombreCampo = fileItem.getFieldName();
                String nombreArchivo = fileItem.getName();
                String extension = nombreArchivo.substring(nombreArchivo.indexOf("."));             
                PortletContext context = request.getPortletSession().getPortletContext();
                String path = context.getRealPath("/images");                   
                File archivo = new File(path + "/" + nombreArchivo);
                PortletContext pc = request.getPortletSession().getPortletContext();
                fileItem.write(archivo);
            } 
        } 
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return true;
}
```

I don't know if I am doing something wrong or this isn't the correct way.
Any idea?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
Finally I tried do it with DLFolderLocalServiceUtil and DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil, but it doesn't work correctly. When I load the page you can see the image, but after, when the page is load completely, the image disappears. 
I don't know if it is because I don't create fine the fileEntry or the url is wrong. 
This is my code:

```
long folderId = CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(DLFolder.class.getName());
DLFolder folder = DLFolderLocalServiceUtil.createDLFolder(folderId);
long userId = themeDisplay.getUserId();
long groupId = themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId();
folder.setUserId(userId);
folder.setGroupId(groupId);
folder.setName("Banner image " + nombreArchivo+String.valueOf(folderId));
DLFolderLocalServiceUtil.updateDLFolder(folder);
ServiceContext serviceContext= ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(DLFileEntry.class.getName(), request);
File myfile =  new File(nombreArchivo);
fileItem.write(myfile); 
List<DLFileEntryType> tip = DLFileEntryTypeLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntryTypes(DLUtil.getGroupIds(themeDisplay));
DLFileEntry DLfileEntry = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(userId, groupId, 0, folderId, null, MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(myfile), nombreArchivo, "Image banner_"+nombreArchivo, "", tip.get(0).getFileEntryTypeId(), null, myfile, fileItem.getInputStream(), myfile.getTotalSpace(), serviceContext);
FileVersion fileVersion = null;
//FileEntry fileEntry = DLAppServiceUtil.getFileEntry(groupId, folderId, nombreArchivo);
//String path = DLUtil.getPreviewURL(fileEntry, fileVersion, themeDisplay, "&imagePreview=1");
String path1 = themeDisplay.getPortalURL()+"/c/document_library/get_file?uuid="+DLfileEntry.getUuid()+"&groupId="+themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId();
String path = "/documents/" + DLfileEntry.getGroupId() + "/" + DLfileEntry.getFolderId() + "/" + DLfileEntry.getTitle()+"/"+DLfileEntry.getUuid();
System.out.println("path " + path);
System.out.println("path " + path1);
prefs.setValue(nombreCampo, path);
```

And this is the output:

```
path /documents/10180/0/cinesa888.png/f24e6da2-0be8-47ad-a3b5-a4ab0d41d17f
path http://localhost:8080/c/document_library/get_file?uuid=f24e6da2-0be8-47ad-a3b5-a4ab0d41d17f&groupId=10180
```

I tried to get the url like lpratlong said (DLUtil) but when I tried to get the FileEntry with DLAppServiceUtil.getFileEntry(..) I have an error that says no exist FileEntry.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.. Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Liferay API to store the file in the Document Library : take a look in DLFolder and DLFileEntry API (for exemple, DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil will show you allowed local operations).
These API will allowed you to store your file in your file system (in the "data" folder of your Liferay installation) and to store reference of your file in Liferay database.

Comment: I was reading this, but I need create a folder and I must do it where just before upload the photo, but I want have  more than one banner and save the image in the same place, but if is different instance of porltet I don't know the folder. I don't know how file system of Liferay works, I don't know if I understood fine. Thanks

Comment: It's not a good thing to save your uploaded file in the "portlet" folder. You're not sure to be able to write in this folder, this folder should be deleted when you'll undeploy your portlet etc...
You should use Liferay API and create a specific DLFolder to store these files.
Could you explain why you need to store the file in your portlet directlty ? IF you still really do that, you can call getRealPath method in your portletContext object.

Comment: Finally I do it with DLFileLocalServiceLocal and DLFolder, but now I have a problem, but I don't know where I can get the path, because I want show the image in view mode, but I don't know ho get it, because if I do: `String path = folder.getPath() + "/"+fileEntry.getName();` the image doesn't appear. Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: You can use this code:
`DLUtil.getPreviewURL(fileEntry, fileVersion, themeDisplay, previewQueryString);`
where previewQueryString == "&imagePreview=1".

You have an example in **view_file_entry.jsp** from Document Library portlet (Liferay 6.1.1).

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it doesn't work... I don't know what. I edited the post to add the problem, maybe you can help me, please. Thanks again

Comment: Please, for your new problem, share piece of code. 
You'd better used DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil instead of DLAppServiceUtil.
Also, could you indicate Liferay version?

Comment: I used DLAppServiceUtil, because with DLLocalServiceUtil I can't get FileEntry, and for DLUtil.getPreviewURL needs a FileEntry. I am using Liferay 6.1.2. And I put the piece of code in the comment. Thanks.